# Proving that if $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} xf(x)=0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}xf''(x)=0$ , then $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}xf'(x)=0$. (using Taylor)

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

Let $f ∈ C^2$  and $f:(0,∞)→R$ be a function such that $\underset{x \rightarrow \infty}{\lim}xf(x)=0$ and $\underset{x \rightarrow \infty}{\lim}xf''(x)=0$.
Prove that $\underset{x \rightarrow \infty}{\lim}xf'(x)=0$.

I somehow feel that this problem needs to be solved using Taylor expansion (taylor series) since it involves derivatives. However, I do not know how to show it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

> I use the following version of Lopital's rule: if $f(x),g(x)$ are differentiable on $(0,\infty)$, with $|g(x)|\to \infty $ as $x\to \infty$. Then $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = L \implies \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = L$$

**Note that no assumption is imposed on $f(x)$.** The proof is reminiscent to that of Stolz's theorem.

---

We use the lopital's rule on the function
$$\frac{e^x f'(x)-e^xf(x)}{e^x}$$

To obtain $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(e^x f'(x)-e^x f(x))'}{(e^x)'} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{e^xf''(x)-e^xf(x)}{e^x} = \lim_{x\to\infty} (f''(x)-f(x))=0$$ Hence $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x f'(x)-e^xf(x)}{e^x} =0=\lim_{x\to\infty}(f'(x)-f(x))$$

This implies $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x) = 0$.

---

Now use lopital's rule on 
$$\frac{xe^x f'(x)-xe^xf(x)}{e^x}$$
To obtain $$\begin{aligned}\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(xe^x f'(x)-xe^x f(x))'}{(e^x)'} &= \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{e^xf'(x)+xe^xf''(x)-e^x f(x)-xe^x f(x)}{e^x} \\ &= \lim_{x\to\infty} (f'(x)+xf''(x)-f(x)-xf(x))=0 \end{aligned}$$ where we used result obtained above. Hence $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{xe^x f'(x)-xe^xf(x)}{e^x} =0=\lim_{x\to\infty}(xf'(x)-xf(x))$$
This implies $\lim_{x\to\infty} xf'(x)=0$.

Comment: This is a respectable use of L'Hospital's Rule. +1

Comment: This is essentially your argument, but yours is much more streamlined :)

Comment: @pisco125 Why does the first step imply that the $limx→∞ f'(x) = 0 $?

Comment: @JeremyGavriel: note that $f$ already tends to $0$ (because $xf$ does so) and it is proved that $f'-f$ tends to $0$ and thus their sum $(f'-f) +f=f'$ also does the same.

Comment: $\sin(x)/x$ tends to 0 as $x$ tends to infinity. However, $\sin(x)$ does not.

Comment: @Robert Yes, that is true, but in this case it's $x$ multiplied by a function (in your example, maybe $x * sinx$ is the better argument. You raise a good point though...

Comment: @pisco125 How can we be sure that the first function where you used L'Hopital is an indeterminate form? Is it enough to just say that the function does not go to zero faster than the speed where $e^x$ goes to infinity?

Comment: @Robert   I used the following version of Lopital's rule: if $f(x),g(x)$ are differentiable on $(0,\infty)$, with $|g(x)|\to \infty $ as $x\to \infty$. Then $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = L \implies \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = L$$ Note that no assumption is imposed on $f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

The theorem mentioned in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2340184/72031) is the key here. Since $f, f''$ both tend to $0$ the derivative $f' $ also tends to $0$. Again note that if $g(x) =xf(x) $ then $g''(x) =xf''(x) +2f'(x) $ and thus $g, g''$ both tend to $0$. By the theorem in linked answer $g' =xf'+f$ tends to $0$ and we are done.

It is also clear from the above that the result holds under the weaker assumption that $xf''(x)$ is bounded as $x\to\infty$.